# Как передать значение из activity в фрагмент и во фрагмент внутри этого фрагмента?

Tags: java, android

В MainActivity отображается Fragment1, внутри этого Fragment1 имеется еще один фрагмент Fragment2. Когда передаю значения из MainActivity в Fragment1 все нормально, но когда нужно дальше из Fragment1 передать данные во Fragment2, который находится внутри этого Fragment1, то приложение вылетает.

Передача из MainActivity в Fragment1:

```
String Id_operEx = "123";
Bundle bundleOP = new Bundle();
String Id_oper = Id_operEx;
bundleOP.putString("Id_oper", Id_oper);
fragment1.setArguments(bundleOP);
```

Получение данных в Fragment1 (тут все приходит нормально):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

String Id_oper = this.getArguments().getString("Id_oper");
textViewId_oper.setText(Id_oper);

//Далее отправка данных из Fragment1 в Fragment2, который внутри этого Fragment1:

Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
final String Id_base2 = textViewId_oper.getText().toString();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
bundle2.putString("Id_oper", Id_base2);
fragment2.setArguments(bundle2);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpagerRelativeLayout, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Получение данных в Fragment2 который внутри Fragment1:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

String Id_oper = this.getArguments().getString("Id_oper");
textView.setText(Id_oper);

}
```

Comment: а ошибка во время вылета присутствует? в логах есть куча красного текста?

Comment: Вылет происходит после добавления строки приема у второго фрагмента: String Id_oper = this.getArguments().getString("Id_oper");

Comment: Набросал приложение-пример. У меня всё работает. Возможно вам надо поиграться с версиями компонентов, т.к. вложенные фрагменты не сразы поддерживались, а начиная с определенной версии